# Overriding standard ID scalar

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I want to use UUID as an identifier but standard scalar ID is coerced as string.
So have to parse uuid from string everywhere I use ID type.

I wonder is it possible to override ID type with my own implementation?
This scalar type has some special meaning or I can just use my own scalar called UUID as identifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can not override the available scalers, please refer this [link](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/issues/1420) for discussion.

You can define a UUIDScalar in your code, for the same you will have to  override the following methods

```java
@Override
public Object serialize(Object dataFetcherResult) {
    //
}

@Override
public Object parseValue(Object input) {
    //
}

@Override
public Object parseLiteral(Object input) {
    //
}
```

Reference: [Making custom scalars in graphql java](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v12/scalars/)

Luckily the code for making custom scalar for UUID is available online, you can use this [PR](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-extended-scalars/pull/18/files)

Comment: The link you have provided was really helpful. Thank you